# bypass a regex filtration to perform an xss attack

Tags: web-application, web-browser, javascript, xss

Does the regex [\w/$!.*-]+$ stop the injection of payloads like :

```
"><script>alert(4)</script>
" onload="alert(4)"
...
```

Comment: It certainly avoids the mentioned examples but it certainly does not stop every possible XSS exploit as in the end it depends on how the user supplied value is actually used.

Comment: what about if it is used like that :

    document.write(
                    "<script type='text/javascript' src='" +
                    var+
                    "'><\/script>");

var is controlled by the regex .

Comment: If var is user controlled, that line allows arbitrary script injection. Why would you want to load a script specified by the user?

Answer (score 2):

No.  This doesn't stop all injections.

You mentioned one example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='INJECTIONPOINT'>
```

The regexp you listed is not enough to stop XSS in that case; an attacker could inject `//www.evil.com/kablooey.js`, and you're done for.  (Comment: the URL `//www.evil.com/kablooey.js` is treated by browsers as equivalent to `http://www.evil.com/kablooey.js`, if the containing page was served over http.)

In general, I recommend reading the OWASP [recommendations](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) on how to prevent XSS.  Sanitize your inputs, and use context-dependent escaping of all outputs (e.g., all values inserted into HTML).

Comment: i compare with my regex what  comes after www.mysite.com/[\w/$!.*-]+$ .now can it be exploited ?

Comment: `www.evil.com/kablooey.js` is actually a relative URL (only the path) that is getting resolved to an absolute URL using the current document’s URL as base. So it won’t load anything from *www.evil.com*.

Comment: so with if i check the src like hat www.mysite.com/[\w/$!.*-]+$ it is impossible to cause a dom based xss ?

Comment: @Gumbo, thank you!  I've fixed the attack to one that actually works.  Now the fixed version *will* load something from www.evil.com.

Comment: @kirowaxoaw, you are heading down the wrong path.  I've already pointed you to the correct path: start by reading the OWASP recommendations, and follow their advice.  Their advice is based upon time-tested experience.